# Is cofinite topology of infinite set $X$ is only $\{X,\varnothing\}$?

Tags: general-topology

I already read some question about cofinite topology of infinite set, but I can't understand it perfectly yet.

I'm in trouble with this.

Let $X = \{a,2a,3a,4a,5a,\ldots, na,\ldots\}$ when $n,a \in\Bbb N$.

Then the cofinite topology I could find is only $\{X, \varnothing\}$ , the indiscrete topology.

I'm trying to understand that closure of $A$ is $A$ if $A$ is finite and is $X$ if $A$ is infinite.

I'm really wondering are there any cofinite topology of infinite set.

Comment: In the cofinite topology on a set $X ,$  any $Y\subsetneqq X$  is closed iff $Y$ is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is incorrect, take a look at $X=\Bbb N$, there are plenty of open sets which are not the whole thing or the empty set, such as $\{2, 3,4,5,\ldots, n+1,\ldots\}$, so the topology is far from indiscrete. You're right that the closure of every non-empty open set is the whole space (since it is the only infinite closed set) but that's not quite the same thing as the topology being indiscrete.

Comment: Thanks really! I have one more question that if {2,3,4,5,…,n+1,…} can be cofinite set? I thought it can't be

Comment: @최선웅 it is cofinite since the complement, $\{1\}$ is finite.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook. Thank you!

Comment: @AdamHughes Im getting confused  why complement of $ \{1\}$ is finite ?  Here $\{1\} \notin \{2, 3,4,5,\ldots, n+1,\ldots\}$ How can say that complement of $ \{1\}$ is finite ?

Comment: @jasmine I think you misread the example--the set that is cofinite (and therefore open) isn't $\{1\}$, it's its complement.

Comment: ohh  ya got it now  thanks u @AdamHughes